# Riding fast on an MTB

Tags: mountain-bike, training, speed

I have been cycling for quite some time now (an MTB - hardtail) and I intend to go for higher speeds above 45kmph (on road). I typically cruise around 38kmph (on road). I can endure my cruise speed pretty well and for very long durations about 2 hours continuous pedalling. But whenever I try to maintain my speed at something above 45kmph like trying to cruise at 50kmph, I run dry pretty fast. Is there a good procedure that I should follow to attain this goal

! - I am specific here about the hardtail mtb. Not the road bikes. 
! - I have good aerobic and cardiovascular as well as muscular strength. Applying force on pedals is not the problem. Consistently putting that output for a good duration is.

Comment: This is wrong place for the question. If the numbers are real - and why would anyone suspect otherwise - you should have no problem getting a real coach. Meanwhile, just participate in time trials on your hardtail.

Comment: @ojs sorry about that, I thought Bicycles SE did take questions regarding training. Also,  in my part of world finding coaches isn't as easy. Although your suggestion in regard of time trials seems promising (didn't come to my mind at all) I'll give it a try. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @ojs If ut seems feasable for any other SE, should it be shifted there then, (I don't know how shifting between SE's works)

Comment: Training is certainly on topic here. The main issue I see is clarity on what you are asking, and support for the surprising speeds you claim. See questions tagged [tag:training] and [tag:power].

Comment: A bit of calculation gives ~400 W for 38 kph on an MTB, ~500 W for 45 kph, and >800 W for 50 kph. If your figures are correct you should switch to road bikes and turn pro immediately!

Comment: At those speeds the major force is air resistance.  Your best option is to try a road bike which is more efficient at cutting through the air than your MTB.

Comment: Also consider using something like Strava to record your rides.  With a tool like this you'll be able to see where you're flagging, and how you compare with other people.

Comment: Fabian Cancellara's gold medal winning TT effort in Rio was just over 45kmh for an hour and 12 minutes. I think your numbers may be off.

Comment: Get more aero with clip on tt bars, skin suit, shoe covers and aero helmet.

Comment: My advice is to start doing 50-100m sprints while riding as fast as you can. You should do them as often as you can and as fast as you can. They do not need to be for a long distance.
Also, you can try to save weight from heavy parts. You will notice the biggest difference in the wheels(rims, tires and hubs). However, that would cost you much.

Comment: Check that you reach that same speed in different speedometers :) but i'd say you are pretty much at the limit on a conventional mountain bike. Any modification to the mountain bike riding style will be just an attempt at turning the mtb into a road bike. If you switch straight away to a road bike you will definitely reach higher cruise and top speed. there are many answer around about making a mtb faster. As for training, if no coach, get books (or PDF :)

Comment: @alex, I think it just matters on the person, I am a simple guy with no coach, but big passion for cycling and living at 1600m above sea, ride in winter and summer, I often go for endurance runs. Maybe that's why. Hard work pays off. I go for offroading a lot and rode on roads as well, but with an MTB. I too first though it ain't possible, but it worked out

Comment: @alex, I think it just matters on the person, I am a simple guy with no coach, but big passion for cycling and living at 1600m above sea, ride in winter and summer, I often go for endurance runs. Maybe that's why. Hard work pays off. I go for offroading a lot and rode on roads as well, but with an MTB. I too first though it ain't possible, but it worked out

Comment: @andy, thank you, maybe I'll try  a road bike someday, cycling is a die hard passion for me, but not the only one. + Money for a road bike is an issue for me now. Maybe someday later

Comment: @criggie, that's a good suggestion, I am going to apply from now onwards

Comment: @superman I did start endurance cycling like that. As for the weight, I can take quite somethings off my bike

Comment: @gaurwraith, I do use quite a few speedometers, like btwin, also I always mark my rides with gps/ beidou/glonass (a bit more regionally accurate) as well. I am my own coach. So PDF's help, if you have any good suggestions. I would really like to hear

Comment: @yawar you are quite fast then. Try to get the cycling bible by Joe Friel, or the ultimate ride by Chris Carmichael for serious long term training plans. Overall fitness will also improve your cycling, core strengthening and flexibility. Since you are at a good level test yourself on climbs, and I would try joining a cycling club as other riders can give you good advice, check those that go faster than you. Mountain bikes are meant to be fast on rough terrain, if you like to go faster you need to go road bike way. Good luck.

Comment: @gaurwraith, I will try climbs, and maybe find a club as well. Thankyou for the suggestion

Comment: @andy256, I used to ride  a heavier MTB, then shifted to a half weight MTB(use it now, is all about this one). Weight shifting nakes you feel like a feather, because when you push as hard for a low weight as for a heavy one, it feels like you are gliding.

Comment: @alex, I don't think Fabian's speed changes, he is too strong than me, he weighs 81kg and I around 55, he's 15 years older than me. I ride in city, with road turns, my speed falls as well, speed breakers. The speed I mentioned is from a run around a lake road with about like 3% gradient with occasional climbs and I was riding down that, maybe that helped. I maxed at 39.2kmph and rode low around 34kmph, with average being ~38kmph. You gave me a person to look up to!, cause I didn't know of him till now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical factors are rolling resistance, wind resistance, gearing, and body posture.

Rolling resistance is minimized with smooth, high-pressure tires.  It's not required that they be super-narrow, but narrower than 2" is probably best for wind resistance.  You should generally run 80-100 PSI.

Wind resistance is minimized by a head-down posture, with arms fairly close to the body.  Changing out the handlebar, or installing bar extensions, may be necessary to optimize this.

Gearing is important if you "max out" your high gear, or you can't find a gear to let you run at optimal cadence.

Body posture (over and above issues of wind resistance) involves having the body "fit" the bike in a way that lets you pedal efficiently at high cadence (and with your head down).  This is more a function of the bike than the other factors, and likely harder to optimize on a mountain bike.

(Remember, maintaining speed on the road is not a matter of putting out maximal force, but rather sustaining power output over a long period of time.  Higher cadence with less force is generally better than maximizing force.  A cadence of 80-100 RPM is generally considered optimal, and a reasonably good first take at balancing force and cadence is to be doing two revs of the crank for every breath you take.)

Oh, and lock out the suspension.

Comment: So, tires do play a role. My pressure is normally around 70 - 75 when off road for traction, and around 85 when on road so I don't have to push. I never locked the suspension? Body posture is low while onroad. Handlebar extensions, I am not familiar with, can you point me in a bit more specific direction

Comment: @yawar That's exceptionally high pressure for a MTB tyre.  Most have a posted maximum of 60 PSI.   Handlebar extensions sound like barends, bolt on bits that poke forward, like mini-sized aerobars.

Comment: @criggie, the tires are 3 inch ones (kenda tires). I get, the handlebars, now let me find 'em and buy them

Comment: @yawar a 3" fatbike tyre  would use a maxmum of 30-40 psi for on road, and as low as 2-5 psi for off road stuff.  You're seriously claiming high thirty km/h for 2 hours on a fatbike with 3" tyres?  Either you're desperately in need of a new speedo, or get some sponsors and start racing on a road bike.

Comment: @criggie, I too doubt myself, so got it checked again by a bike mechanic instead of me this time. The markings are fade, but we figured out the model of tire and got it from the book. It's (26 x 2.10) and the pressure is min(40) and max(65), he said my pressure gauge is not calibrated correctly or maybe the spring isn't fit well. I checked again with him about the pressures, turns out, I ride at 50 - 55psi offroad and around 63psi on road. Sponsors ah!. I would maybe look for one if I get super serious about pro cycling.

Comment: @criggie, now that I know my correct tire pressures, it seems a bit low. according to Daniel, 90 - 100 psi would suffice. Is there even such a tire that reachs 100 psi at 2 inches? Also I think the comments are diverting from the answer's topic maybe we should shift to talk!

Comment: road bike tyres are often 80-120 PSI but they're 23 or 25 millimetres.  Your 3 inch tyre is 75 millimetres.

Comment: @Criggie -  I run my 35mm touring tires at 90-100psi.

Comment: @Criggie - Opie just said his tires are 2.1".

Answer (score 1):

I can't go that fast on my mountain bike on the flat, but if you want to increase speed at that rate, aerodynamics is what you need to work on. So put your elbows in, duck lower and get into a more aerodynamic position.

I doubt it will give you that much extra speed, but it will certainly help.